# How to make page scroll to back top when new content loads in an SPA?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, octobercms

I'm using [octoberCMS](https://octobercms.com/plugin/imbasynergy-octoberspa) with Single Page Application Plugin. I've added [smooth-scrollbar.js](https://idiotwu.github.io/smooth-scrollbar/).

Everything works perfectly, except that I can't get smooth-scrollbar to scroll back to the top when a new page is loaded.

Here's the API documentation at [Github](https://github.com/idiotWu/smooth-scrollbar/blob/17ce0196c0fdce5bdceda8ef5316e705e0f62d30/docs/api.md)

```
<div id="my-scrollbar" data-scrollbar>
 <div id="content">
   <div id="spa-page-content">
    {% page %}
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Please bear with me, as I'm new to this and learning :)

Thanks a lot, You'll make my day!

Comment: You can use [`setPosition()`](https://github.com/idiotWu/smooth-scrollbar/blob/17ce0196c0fdce5bdceda8ef5316e705e0f62d30/docs/api.md#scrollbarsetposition) to make the page scroll back to the top. The tricky part is knowing when content has been loaded. Research the docs of octoberCMS to find out if it exposes an event on page change/update which you can hook to

Answer (score 0):

You can create an observer that reacts to content change. I used this nifty library, [scrollTo.js](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) for nice scrolling control. Here is an example on one of my projects. Using Jquery `on` method with a parent element on my page I then watch for content change.

```
   $('#{$section}').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
        let postTitle = $('#postTitle');
        if (postTitle.length > 0) {
            $('body').scrollTo('#bms-blog', {offset: -115});
        }
    });
```